# How to place labels at the end of arrows and how to break lines inside TikZ nodes?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to replicate this block diagram but I'm having trouble with certain details. This is the block diagram that I'm trying to replicate:

[image]

This is what I have:

[image]

I just need help in with the letters in the blocks I can't manage to put one word under another, also I want to make the arrows line and head a little more bold and thick and finally I need to find a way to write something at the right side of the arrows.

Here is the code for the second figure:

```
\documentclass{beamer} 
\usetheme{Boadilla}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{tikz}  
\usepackage{mathtools} 
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows} 
\usepackage{subfig} 
\usepackage{babel,blindtext} 
\usepackage{subcaption}

\usefonttheme{professionalfonts} % using non standard fonts for beamer
\usefonttheme{serif} % default family is serif

% \title{Ejemplo de Diseño de un Controlador}
\author{Julio Ortegón} 
% \institute{Universidad de los Andes} 
\date{}
\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{frame}{}

\centering

\bigskip 
\bigskip
    
\tikzstyle{block} = [draw, fill=white, rectangle, 
    minimum height=3em, minimum width=6em   ]
\tikzstyle{Fi} = [coordinate]
\tikzstyle{Rd} = [coordinate] 
\tikzstyle{Qd} = [coordinate]  
\tikzstyle{Qa} = [coordinate] 
\tikzstyle{Wd} = [coordinate] 
\tikzstyle{QCHP} = [coordinate]  
\tikzstyle{aRQ} = [coordinate] 
\tikzstyle{pinstyle} = [pin edge={to-,ultra thick,black}] 

\begin{tikzpicture}[auto, node distance=2cm,>=latex']
%Declara los nodos
\node [Fi, name=Fi] {}; 
\node [block, right of=Fi] (CHP) {\textbf{CHP} $n_W,n_Q$ };  
\node [QCHP, name =QCHP, right of=CHP,node distance = 2.5 cm] {}; 
\node [Qa,name=Qa, right of=QCHP, node distance = 2.5cm,label={right:$Q_a$}] {};
\node[aRQ,name=aRQ,above of=Qa, node distance = 1.5cm]{}; 
\node [block, right of=aRQ,node distance = 1.2cm] (WARG) {\textbf{WARG} };   
\node[Rd,name=Rd, right of=WARG, node distance = 2cm,label={right:$R_d$}] {};  
\node[Qd,name=Qd,below of=Qa,node distance = 1.5cm, right = 3.25cm,label={right:$Q_d$}]{};  
\node[Wd,name=Wd,below of=Qd,node distance = 1.5cm, right = 0.1cm,label={right:$W_d$}]{}; 

% \draw [->] (Controller1) -- node[name= ] {$ $} (system);
% \node [output, right of=system] (output) {};
% \node [block, below = 2 cm, right = 4cm] (Controller2) {$1+sK_h$}; 

%Ahora conectamos los bloques 

\draw [draw,->] (Fi) -- node {$F_i$} (CHP); 
\draw [->] (CHP) -- node {$Q^{\text{CHP}}$} (QCHP);  
\draw [->] (QCHP) -- node {$\alpha^{\text{CHP}}_{\text{aQ}}Q^{\text{CHP}}$} (Qa);   
\draw [->] (QCHP) |- node {$\qquad\qquad\qquad\;\; \alpha^{\text{CHP}}_{\text{RQ}}Q^{\text{CHP}}$} (aRQ);   
\draw [->] (WARG) -- node {} (Rd); 
\draw [->] (QCHP) |- node {$\qquad\qquad\qquad\;\; \alpha^{\text{CHP}}_{\text{QQ}}Q^{\text{CHP}}$} (Qd); 
\draw [->] (CHP) |- node {$\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\; W^{\text{CHP}}$} (Wd);


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame} 

 
\end{document}
```

I appreciate the help.

Comment: I found a way to put the labels on the right on the arrow head it's already changed on the code above. It's done by adding a label={} statement when declaring a node for example: 
\node[Qd,name=Qd,below of=Qa,node distance = 1.5cm, right = 3.25cm,label={right:$Q_d$}]{};

Comment: You don't need such complicated code. You can just add another node at the end of the path. See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest a few improvements of your code.

First, I would use `\tikzset` instead of `\tikzstyle`, since it is much easier to define multiple styles this way.

Second, instead of using empty nodes that you style as `coordinate`s, you can directly define `\coordinate`s at a certain position and name them using `(name)`. This naming technique also works with nodes.

Then, in order to later easier place the label nodes, I added two helper coordinates. I also adjusted the alignments of the `WARG` and the `Wd` nodes.

You can align nodes on paths using the `pos`, `above`, `below`, `right` or `left` options and by placing them at the right position in the path: If you place the node last, it will be put at the end of the path. You can place multiple nodes on one path.

To have a line break inside a node, you need to set its alignment using the `align` option. Then you can use `\\` to insert a forced line break.

```
\documentclass[border=1mm, tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows} 

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\tikzset{
    block/.style={draw, fill=white, rectangle, 
    minimum height=3em, minimum width=6em},
    every path/.style={very thick},
}

\begin{tikzpicture}[auto, node distance=2cm, >=latex']
%Declara los nodos
\coordinate (Fi) at (0,0); 
\node [block, right of=Fi, align=center] (CHP) {\textbf{CHP} \\ $n_W,n_Q$};  
\coordinate [right of=CHP, node distance=2.5cm] (QCHP); 
\coordinate [right of=QCHP, node distance=2.5cm] (Qa);  
\coordinate [above of=Qa, node distance=1.5cm] (aRQ); 
\node [block, anchor=west] at (aRQ) (WARG) {\textbf{WARG}};   
\coordinate [right of=WARG, node distance=2cm] (Rd);  
\coordinate [below of=Qa, node distance=1.5cm, right=3.25cm] (Qd);  
\coordinate [below of=Qd, node distance=1.5cm] (Wd); 

\coordinate [below of=Qa, node distance=1.5cm] (helper 1);
\coordinate [below of=QCHP, node distance=3cm] (helper 2);

%Ahora conectamos los bloques 

\draw [->] (Fi) -- node {$F_i$} (CHP); 
\draw [->] (CHP) -- (QCHP) node[above, xshift=-20pt] {$Q^{\text{CHP}}$};  
\draw [->] (QCHP) -- (Qa) node[above, xshift=-30pt] {$\alpha^{\text{CHP}}_{\text{aQ}}Q^{\text{CHP}}$} node[right] {$Q_a$};   
\draw [->] (QCHP) |- (aRQ) node[above, xshift=-30pt] {$\alpha^{\text{CHP}}_{\text{RQ}}Q^{\text{CHP}}$};   
\draw [->] (WARG) -- (Rd) node[right] {$R_d$};
\draw [->] (QCHP) |- (helper 1) node[above, xshift=-30pt] {$\alpha^{\text{CHP}}_{\text{QQ}}Q^{\text{CHP}}$} -- (Qd) node[right] {$Q_d$};
\draw [->] (CHP) |- (helper 2) node[above, xshift=-20pt] {$W^{\text{CHP}}$} -- (Wd) node[right] {$W_d$};


\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]